# Trying to distinguish between two 2 variables Java

Tags: java, if-statement

Im trying to display percentages of games won and drawn between two selected teams, but im finding it hard to distinguish between either team.

```
Connection con = DBConnector.connect();
             ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT t1.title AS title1, t2.title AS title2, g.score1, g.score2, g.winner AS winner, g.team1_id AS team1,  g.home AS home FROM games g INNER JOIN teams AS t1 ON g.team1_id = t1.id INNER JOIN teams AS t2 ON g.team2_id = t2.id WHERE (t1.title = '"+team1 +"' AND t2.title = '" +team2+ "') OR (t1.title = '"+team2 +"' AND t2.title = '" +team1+ "');");
            while(rs.next()){

                if(rs.getString("team1").equals(rs.getString("home"))){
                if(rs.getInt("winner") == 1){
                        teamOneWin++;
                    }else{
                        teamTwoWin++;
                    }

                }else if(rs.getInt("winner") == 2){
                    if(rs.getString("team1").equals(rs.getString("home"))){
                        teamOneWin++;
                    }else{
                        teamTwoWin++;
                    }

                }else if(rs.getInt("winner") == 0){
                    if(rs.getString("team1").equals(rs.getString("home"))){
                    draw++;
                    }


            }
```

I am checking if the team1 value from the query, equals the home team value in the query. If they equal and team 1 is the value in column winner, i want teamOneWin to increment.  I specify winner 1, winner 2 and winner 0 (match is a draw). I specify these because i have a winner 3 value which is not played also.

The line below i know is flawed, as team1 always equals home team, but i need a way to differentiate either team and increment the correct one upon winner value.

```
if(rs.getString("team1").equals(rs.getString("home"))){
```

Would using a COUNT in my SQL be a better result?

Here is the table structure of my games table:

```
CREATE TABLE "games" (
    "team1_id"  integer NOT NULL,
    "team2_id"  integer NOT NULL,
    "home"  integer,
    "score1"    varchar DEFAULT null,
    "score2"    varchar DEFAULT null,
    "winner"    integer,
    "created_at"    DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY("team1_id","created_at"),
    FOREIGN KEY("team1_id") REFERENCES "teams"("id"),
    FOREIGN KEY("team2_id") REFERENCES "teams"("id")
);
```

And here is the table structure of my table teams:

```
CREATE TABLE "teams" (
    "id"    integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "title" varchar NOT NULL,
    "code"  varchar,
    "synonyms"  varchar,
    "address"   varchar,
    "web"   varchar,
    "created_at"    DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Many thanks.

Comment: This seems like it would be better to do using `COUNT`s in the SQL rather than loading in all the data from the DB and manually counting it in Java.

Comment: Would the count read exactly like my if, where winner is equal to a number and also team id?

Comment: All depends on how your write the SQL - it might help if you include the table structure of the `games` and `teams` tables in your question (including data types and any foreign key relationships)

Comment: please check my edit, I've just included both.

Comment: I think the problem you're really suffering from is that your data model doesn't make it terribly easy to get at the data you're trying to get. Rather than using the value `3` in the `winner` column to indicate that a game hasn't been played, create a `BIT` column that tells you whether or not that game has been played. That lets you store the ID of the winning team in the `winner` column (or leave it blank if a draw), which makes gathering the stats a lot easier for you as you can now count the number of rows where a given teamId is in the `winner` column where those two teams were playing.

Comment: And for the sake of example, what would the COUNT of my SQL look like with this format? with the winner column exactly

Comment: With the data structure in its current format it'd likely be too long for a comment. You might also want to consider writing this sort of data out to a separate statistics table so that you aren't calculating it on the fly *ever*, at which point it becomes a trivial read from a table.

Comment: What is your rdbms? Also do you just want the percentage of the dtaws over all the matches between the 2 selected teams?

Comment: Im using SQLite and yes, just percentages between games of wins for either selected side and draws

Comment: @JonK can you please write it as an answer? A trivial read from my tables is satisfactory for now. I'm just confused how i make 3 count statements in one query, whilst having these similar where conditions still applying.

Comment: @JonK - I've implemented your theory and im trying to sum them but:     sum(case when g.winner = t1.id  then 1 else 0 end) onewins,
 sum(case when g.winner = t2.id   then 1 else 0 end) twowins gives me the incorrect answer. How can i store t2.id as an int?

Comment: Which theory? The statistics table wouldn't require any summing at all - it'd be a straight read.

Comment: I have figured it out, i was talking about your played bit column approach. Ending up passing the team id's through the controllers. Thanks for all your help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, in the column `winner` of the `games` table, you store an integer value indicating:

```
0: draw
1 or 2: either team won
3: game not played
```

If this is the case then I think that you can get the results you need without fetching the data from the database and iterating over each row. 
Try this query:

```
select 
  t.title1, t.title2,
  100.0 * t.draws / (t.draws + t.wins) percentdraws,
  100.0 * t.wins / (t.draws + t.wins) percentwins
from (
  select 
    'team1' title1, 'team2' title2,
    sum(case when g.winner = 0 then 1 else 0 end) draws,
    sum(case when g.winner <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) wins
  from games g 
  inner join teams t1 on t1.id = g.team1_id 
  inner join teams t2 on t2.id = g.team2_id
  where 
    ((t1.title = 'team1' and t2.title = 'team2') or (t2.title = 'team1' and t1.title = 'team2'))
    and 
    g.winner < 3
) t
```

Change `'team1'` and `'team2'` to the names of the selected teams.

Comment: This is exactly what i need, thanks. I've made a few changes to this query, such as adding a team1 wins and team2. How can i make percentdraws, percentwinsone or percentwinstwo equal 0 if the value is null?

Comment: How can it be null?

Comment: if say one of these teams doesn't have a win

Comment: In sql you can transform anything to 0 when it is null with coalesce(), like `coalesce(something, 0)`. This returns `something` if it is not null and 0 if it is null.

Comment: so something like coalesce(100.0 * t.draws / (t.draws + t.onewins + t.twowins, 0)) percentdraws ?

Comment: Yes, if `100.0 * t.draws / (t.draws + t.onewins + t.twowins` returns null then the result will be 0

Comment: Check the parentheses: `coalesce(100.0 * t.draws / (t.draws + t.onewins + t.twowins), 0)`